# Checking data integrity for cloned drive

Tags: data-integrity, dd

I have n disk clones  that need to be checked against the source.  I am looking for an efficient way to do this.  Already tried md5sum and sha256sum but these take several minutes on a multi-gig drive and wont produce the intended result with drives of slightly differing sizes.

background info:

- I am building an SD cloning tool.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You might try to use a lower bit version of SHA. Otherwise, you really can't get around the time it takes to hash.